# Compare Two Liste <T>

Tags: c#, comparison

how can i compare 2 list  ?

```
public class Pers_Ordre : IEqualityComparer<Pers_Ordre>
{
    int _ordreId;
    public int LettreVoidID
    {
        get { return _LettreVoidID; }
        set { _LettreVoidID = value; }
    }

    string _OrdreCummul;
    public string OrdreCummul
    {
        get { return _OrdreCummul; }
        set { _OrdreCummul = value; }
    }

    // Products are equal if their names and product numbers are equal. 
    public bool Equals(Pers_Ordre x, Pers_Ordre y)
    {

        //Check whether the compared objects reference the same data. 
        if (Object.ReferenceEquals(x, y)) return true;

        //Check whether any of the compared objects is null. 
        if (Object.ReferenceEquals(x, null) || Object.ReferenceEquals(y, null))
            return false;

        //Check whether the products' properties are equal. 
        return x.LettreVoidID == y.LettreVoidID && x.OrdreCummul == y.OrdreCummul;
    }

    // If Equals() returns true for a pair of objects  
    // then GetHashCode() must return the same value for these objects. 

    public int GetHashCode(Pers_Ordre product)
    {
        //Check whether the object is null 
        if (Object.ReferenceEquals(product, null)) return 0;

        //Get hash code for the Name field if it is not null. 
        int hashProductName = product.OrdreCummul == null ? 0 : product.OrdreCummul.GetHashCode();

        //Get hash code for the Code field. 
        int hashProductCode = product.LettreVoidID.GetHashCode();

        //Calculate the hash code for the product. 
        return hashProductName ^ hashProductCode;
    }
}
```

and i compare like this:

```
private void simpleButton_Comparer_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string LeFile_Client = System.IO.Path.Combine(appDir, @"FA.csv");
    string LeFile_Server = System.IO.Path.Combine(appDir, @"FA_Server.csv");

    List<Pers_Ordre> oListClient = Outils.GetCsv(LeFile_Client).OrderBy(t => t.LettreVoidID).ToList();
    List<Pers_Ordre> oListServert = Outils.GetCsvServer(LeFile_Server).OrderBy(t => t.LettreVoidID).ToList(); 

    List<Pers_Ordre> LeDiff = new List<Pers_Ordre>();

    LeDiff = oListServert.Except(oListClient).ToList();

    string Noid = "", OdreID = "";

    foreach (var oDiff in LeDiff)
    {
        Noid += oDiff.LettreVoidID + " ";
        OdreID += oDiff.OrdreCummul + " ";
    }

    MessageBox.Show(Noid + "--" + OdreID);
}
```

i can not get the right result.

The Lists contain class objects and we would like to iterate through one list, looking for the same item in a second List and report any differences.

to get object that contains in List A but not in List B
and vice versa.

Comment: do you mean you want `list.Union(list2)` or  `list.Intersect(list2)`?

Comment: Are you trying to find objects present in one list but not both, or something else?

Comment: Define "any differences."  Are you looking for instances in one list which aren't in another?  Are you looking for an instance in both lists and reporting differences between that instance in the two lists?  It's not clear.

Answer (score 1):

Your current `.Except()` call will find items from Server that are missing on the client, but it will not find items on the client that are missing on the server.

Try this:

```
private void simpleButton_Comparer_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string LeFile_Client = System.IO.Path.Combine(appDir, @"FA.csv");
    string LeFile_Server = System.IO.Path.Combine(appDir, @"FA_Server.csv");

    var ListClient = Outils.GetCsv(LeFile_Client).OrderBy(t => t.LettreVoidID);
    var ListServer = Outils.GetCsvServer(LeFile_Server).OrderBy(t => t.LettreVoidID); 
    var LeDiff = ListServer.Except(ListClient).Concat(ListClient.Except(ListServer));

    var result = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (var Diff in LeDiff)
    {
        result.AppendFormat("{0} --{1} ", Diff.LettreVoidID, Diff.OrdreCummul);
    }
    MessageBox.Show(Noid.ToString() + "--" + OdreID);
}
```

This code should also be significantly faster than your original, as it avoids loading the results into memory until it builds the final string. This code in performs the equivalent of two separate sql LEFT JOINs. We could make it faster still by doing one FULL JOIN, but that would require writing our own linq operator method as well.

Comment: @JimMischel Yep, no need. But if we ever take the time to build that full join operator, sorting first will be much faster :)